# linux asm problem: calling extern function

Tags: linux, assembly

On linux

### file1.s:

```
.text
.globl MyFunc
Func:
        ....
 call my_jump
 ret
```

### file2.h:

```
extern "C" FUNC_NO_RETURN  void  my_jump();
```

### file3.cpp:

```
extern "C" __attribute__((noinline)) void my_jump()
{
     return;
}
```

when linking my module which calls "MyFunc", i get the following error: (previosly before adding a call to my_jump inside the asm code, everything was OK)

`"relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against 'longjmp_hack' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"`

any ideas?

Comment: More info needed:

- do you use GCC or do you use LD directly to link the objects? Also, which commandline paramaters do you use?
- Why the "attribute((noinline))" statement?

Comment: Did you *try* re-compiling with `-fPIC` ???

Comment: I am using g++ for linkage.i found out that i need to add  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) my function declaration in file2.h.  however, i cannot figure out why do i need that, since i as i read this flag suppose to aggregate different function declarations to the same object within shared object linkage, but i define this function only once!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the FUNC_NO_RETURN from file2.h

e.g. **file2.h:**

> extern "C"  void  my_jump();

and **file4.c:**

```
#include "file2.h"  
extern "C" void MyFunc();  
main(){  
   MyFunc();  
}
```

and fixing the typo in the **file1.s** :

```
.text  
.globl MyFunc  
MyFunc:  
  call my_jump  
  ret
```

and it all compile fine for me....

> g++ file1.s file3.cpp file4.c -o a.out

Version of compiler;

> $ g++ --version
>   g++ (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1)

Linux version: 3.1.5-6.fc16.x86_64